# Playing Sounds Automatically when going to a new view controller

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I am trying to make a simple reading flash card ios app for esl students using swift.

How can I take what I know about using buttons to play sounds, and have the sounds play automatically when a new page/view is loaded up on the phone? It seems really simple, but I can't figure it out.

This is what I have for the button

```
var error: NSERROR?
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
audioPlayer.preparetoPlay()
audioPlayer.play()
```

Again this works for the button, but I figure it has something to do with the last 2 lines.

For example: After hitting start there is a picture of a Computer. How I have it now is when you click the computer, a voice says the word, and spells it.

I want it to be really intrinsic in case "Click here" doesn't resonate with the class (these are real esl students!) so I would like to have it automatically play.

Thanks!

Comment: You can put the code to play inside the viewDidLoad() function call of the ViewController object

Comment: http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/01/ios-essentials-the-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle/

Answer (score 0):

Place your code inside the `viewDidLoad()` method of each view controller as such:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    var error: NSERROR?
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
    audioPlayer.preparetoPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```